# Overloading rules in the Qt resource system

Tags: qt

In my application the main executable and several (dynamically loaded) shared libraries contain [Qt resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). It seems to load all of them, and the union of all resources is available. What happens if multiple resources have a file with the same name? Does the first or last take precedence, or is it random/undefined? Is there any way to access resources from specific files? Can a plugin override resources in the main application?

I'm aware that this can be avoided by sensible use of paths, I'm just asking what the rules are as it doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: Why? They're working fine, I was just wondering what would happen if I accidentally created different files with the same name in two plugins.

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource system registers one resource per name, and which resource exactly is going to have a given name depends only on the library load order: not something you can always control. It doesn't even matter if the first or last resource with a given name "wins". You can't depend on any of it, it might not even behave the same across the platforms, so you have no way but to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

From this [thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/6911/how-dynamic-plugins-work-with-resources/4) it looks like you will definitely run into problems if you have conflicting names. That's a bit odd IMO, it would make more sense for every binary to resolve resources from its own embedded resource file. But it is not how Qt works, so if you want to avoid name conflicts, use a unique folder prefix for every plugin.